# MongoDB Unwind taking too much time

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, left-join, query-performance

I have a collection in MongoDB with millions of documents.
These are read only once created.
docs : { _id : xxx, name : 'John', .. }, ...

I am using another collection to maintain keywords for the documents
Keywords can be attached or removed from the documents.
keyc : { _id : xxx, ..., keywords : ["key1", ..."keyN"] }, ..

I want list of all the documents which are not having a particular keyword.
For this, I am using lookup in aggregation query on docs collection.

```
$lookup : {
      from: 'keyc',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'keys'
    }
```

When add unwind stage :

```
    $unwind : {
      path: '$keys',
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
```

This query is taking >5 mins (~480 seconds).

My keys collection is empty at this point (No difference in preserveNullAndEmptyArrays true or false).

Is there anyway this can be optimized?

Comment: At the start add the `$match` stage so that the match criteria will take only that documents on which required operation need to perform.Then after that try adding the `lookup` stage. It will might reduce the timestamp.

Comment: Did you find a way to optimize that?